# Jetty SSL configuration Apache karaf

Tags: ssl, jetty, apache-karaf, jetty-8

I am trying to configure the jetty to work with SSL in Apache Karaf OSGI container.
http works, but https does not work. What could be the problem?

My configuration details below:

etc/jetty.xml

```
<Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <Set name="host">
                <Property name="jetty.host" />
            </Set>
            <Set name="port">
                <Property name="jetty.port" default="8282" />
            </Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
            <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
            <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
            <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
            <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
            <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</Call>
<Call name="addConnector">
 <Arg>
   <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
     <Arg>
       <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl.SslContextFactory">
         <Set name="KeyStore">/opt/keystore</Set>
    <Set name="KeyStorePassword">password</Set>
    <Set name="KeyManagerPassword">password</Set>
    <Set name="TrustStore">/opt/keystore</Set>
    <Set name="TrustStorePassword">password</Set>
       </New>
     </Arg>
     <Set name="port">8443</Set>
     <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
   </New>
 </Arg>
```

entry in /etc/org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg file

```
org.ops4j.pax.web.config.file=${karaf.home}/etc/jetty.xml
```

Answer (score 7):

To enable SSL, you just need to enable it by using the httpService configuration. 
For this edit the etc/org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg and add/alter the following entries.

```
org.osgi.service.http.secure.enabled=true
```

more details on how to configure Pax Web and the httpService can be found at the [official dokumentation](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxweb/Configuration), or the [integration tests](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/tree/master/pax-web-itest/pax-web-itest-container/pax-web-itest-container-jetty)