# How to add a SSL connector for apache karaf?

Tags: ssl, apache-karaf, jetty-9

While searching for an answer to this question I stumbled upon http://blog.nanthrax.net/2013/02/multiple-http-connectors-in-apache-karaf/ and [Jetty SSL configuration Apache karaf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24448874/1851290) but this information is outdated. I found the new documentation at https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-connectors.html and the examples differ from proposed configurations. Apache Karaf 4.0.2 seems to use Jetty 9.

I already have a keystore at ${karaf.home}/etc/keystores/keystore.jks and would like just to add a second ssl connector at port 14000. How to do that?

Here's my org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg:

```
org.osgi.service.http.port=8181

org.osgi.service.http.port.secure=8443
org.osgi.service.http.secure.enabled=true
org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.keystore=./etc/keystores/keystore.jks
org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.password=password
org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.keypassword=password

org.ops4j.pax.web.config.file=${karaf.home}/etc/jetty.xml
```

Here's my jetty.xml:

```xml
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
    <Call name="addConnector">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
                <Arg name="server">
                    <Ref refid="Server" />
                </Arg>
                <Arg name="factories">
                    <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
                        <Item>
                            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory"></New>
                        </Item>
                        <Item>
                            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory"></New>
                        </Item>
                    </Array>
                </Arg>
                <Set name="host">
                    <Property name="jetty.host" default="0.0.0.0" />
                </Set>
                <Set name="port">
                    <Property name="jetty.port" default="14000" />
                </Set>
                <Set name="idleTimeout">
                    <Property name="http.timeout" default="30000" />
                </Set>
                <Set name="name">restConnector:14000</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>
</Configure>
```

I had to set name like this to workaround an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 1` in pax-web-jetty-4.2.2.jar at `org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.ServerControllerImpl$Stopped.start(ServerControllerImpl.java:503)`:

```java
String[] split = connector.getName().split(":");
if (httpSecurePort == Integer.valueOf(split[1])
        .intValue()
        && address.equalsIgnoreCase(split[0])) { ... }
```

Now the connector seems to start from what I see in the log:

```
2016-02-03 13:39:19,821 | INFO  | pool-60-thread-1 | JettyServerImpl                  | 128 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.2 | Pax Web available at [localhost]:[14000]
2016-02-03 13:39:19,821 | INFO  | pool-60-thread-1 | JettyFactoryImpl                 | 128 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.2 | SPDY not available, creating standard ServerConnector for Http
2016-02-03 13:39:19,822 | INFO  | pool-60-thread-1 | JettyServerImpl                  | 128 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.2 | Pax Web available at [0.0.0.0]:[8181]
2016-02-03 13:39:19,825 | INFO  | pool-60-thread-1 | JettyFactoryImpl                 | 128 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.2 | No ALPN class available
2016-02-03 13:39:19,825 | INFO  | pool-60-thread-1 | JettyFactoryImpl                 | 128 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.2 | SPDY not available, creating standard ServerConnector for Https
2016-02-03 13:39:19,825 | INFO  | pool-60-thread-1 | JettyServerImpl                  | 128 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.2 | Pax Web available at [0.0.0.0]:[8443]
...
2016-02-03 14:02:03,493 | INFO  | pool-54-thread-1 | ContextHandler                   | 115 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | Started HttpServiceContext{httpContext=org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManagerHttpContext@33dd06a6}
2016-02-03 14:02:03,493 | INFO  | pool-54-thread-1 | Server                           | 115 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | jetty-9.2.10.v20150310
2016-02-03 14:02:03,571 | INFO  | pool-54-thread-1 | ServerConnector                  | 115 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | Started restConnector:14000@1ed3b7fb{SSL-HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:14000}
2016-02-03 14:02:03,571 | INFO  | pool-54-thread-1 | ServerConnector                  | 115 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | Started default@723f99b6{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8181}
2016-02-03 14:02:03,602 | INFO  | pool-54-thread-1 | ServerConnector                  | 115 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | Started secureDefault@15203cf8{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8443}
2016-02-03 14:02:03,602 | INFO  | pool-54-thread-1 | Server                           | 115 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | Started @14307ms
```

But if I try to open https://localhost:14000/ in my browser I get `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` and the following exception is thrown:

```
2016-02-03 15:46:00,509 | DEBUG | qtp427346077-223 | HttpConnection                   | 79 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 |
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1431)[:1.8.0_60]
...
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)[:1.8.0_60]
```

Do I miss something in the jetty configuration?

Answer (score 2):

After hours of trying out different configurations and debugging with eclipse debugger plus `log:set DEBUG` in karaf I finally came to the right configuration. Here it is:

```xml
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <New id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
    <Set name="KeyStorePath"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/etc/keystores/keystore.jks</Set>
    <Set name="KeyStorePassword">OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4</Set>
    <Set name="KeyManagerPassword">OBF:1u2u1wml1z7s1z7a1wnl1u2g</Set>
    <Set name="TrustStorePath"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/etc/keystores/keystore.jks</Set>
    <Set name="TrustStorePassword">OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4</Set>
  </New>
  <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
        <Arg name="server">
          <Ref refid="Server" />
        </Arg>
        <Arg name="factories">
          <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
            <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory">
                <Arg name="next">http/1.1</Arg>
                <Arg name="sslContextFactory"><Ref refid="sslContextFactory"/></Arg>
              </New>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory"></New>
            </Item>
          </Array>
        </Arg>
        <Set name="host">
          <Property name="jetty.host" default="0.0.0.0" />
        </Set>
        <Set name="port">
          <Property name="jetty.port" default="14000" />
        </Set>
        <Set name="idleTimeout">
          <Property name="http.timeout" default="30000" />
        </Set>
        <Set name="name">restConnector:14000</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

The crucial points are:

- Pick a connector name with a colon to workaround [PAXWEB-907](https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXWEB-907)
- An instance of `SslContextFactory` should be created with keystore properties and referenced in `SslConnectionFactory`
- It is needed to declare both `SslConnectionFactory` and `HttpConnectionFactory` whereby it is important to declare them right in this order.

Comment: as alternative to the PAXWEB-907 issue do an upgrade to Karaf 4.0.4 which includes a fix for this.

Comment: I have to stick to Karaf 4.0.2 at the moment.

Comment: How do you make Apache Karaf read jetty.xml ? org.ops4j.pax.web.config.file=${karaf.home}/etc/jetty.xml does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to face the same situation that I passed pretty easily. I created my own jks self-signed and then configured only Pax Web via cfg files.

1. Create JKS

   keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -validity 2048 \
    -alias dontesta-karaf \
    -dname "cn=karaf.dontesta.it, ou=R&D Labs, o=Antonio Musarra's Blog, C=IT, L=Rome, S=Italy" \
    -keypass changeit -storepass changeit \
    -keystore dontesta-karaf-server.jks \
    -ext SAN=DNS:www.dontesta.it,DNS:services.dontesta.it
2. Configure CFG Pax Web

   javax.servlet.context.tempdir = /Users/amusarra/Progetti/Karaf/runtime/apache-karaf-4.0.8/data/pax-web-jsp
   org.ops4j.pax.web.config.file = /Users/amusarra/Progetti/Karaf/runtime/apache-karaf-4.0.8/etc/jetty.xml
   org.osgi.service.http.port = 8181

   org.osgi.service.http.secure.enabled=true
   org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.keystore=${karaf.etc}/keystore/dontesta-karaf-server.jks
   org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.password=changeit
   org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.keypassword=changeit

For more info can you see at https://www.dontesta.it/blog/2017/03/02/come-abilitare-https-apache-karaf-pax-web/